# Remote Mysql Curl or Cron? Advice

Tags: php, mysql, curl, cron

This may sound silly but i am not sure if i am taking the right path. I am working on a intranet closed to the www. I have a calendar that is updated daily and i want to display used timeslots on the public website for specific users to make appoinments. Now i dont want to expose the intranet to the outer world for security reasons, so i replicate the table on the remote server to update it from my localhost and this leave me with a few options that i can think of:

```
1) Run a cron that update my local table and remote table each 10 minutes.     
   This work ok but that 10 min gap (or x min gap) may cause overlapping and i am not fan to query 
   the db without need specially the local one.
2) Allow mysql remote access of the remote server only to the IP of the local server and 
   this would update the remote tables in real time when the user add an event locally.
   This is the path i am taking as is fast and will avoid overlapping but not sure if its the best way.
   Im not using SSL o tunnel for this, as the remote table is just a copy of the local one, 
   i will just have to run by force a cron to ask for new data on the remote server and if so
   update the local one.
3) Use curl as to talk with the remote server and vice versa and let them handle the db
   individually. This one is really slow on my tests and a bit tricky to post query results 
   via curl plus this would have to run on a cron as well taking me back to the point 1)
```

If there is any better way or advice on the idea i will appreciate any lights.

Comment: Do you have several "local" copies all making changes at the same time?  Essentially do the changes need to go both ways, do you need to update the local with the remote and vice versa

Comment: One other popular way is to build a microservice (JSON/XML) that reads directly from the database but only displays content relevant to your application. Your public site can then talk to it and get what it wants. It is up to you to build authentication on your microservice but even without it, it is a relatively secure approach.

Comment: ArtisiticPhoenix no is just one table locally and the same remotely, i need to update the local only if something was added on the remote one, but the local one is a busy one.

Comment: Spade i will check that approach thanks